# Undefined function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Function `letswin()` not working. I couldnt find a way to fix.

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '.html' );
var pathArray = pathArray.reverse();
var pathArray = pathArray .join('');
var pathArray= pathArray .split('/');
var bidnum=pathArray[3];
$(document).ready(function(){           
    $('body').append("<div id=\"cdjs\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 30px; background-color: gray; box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px; left: 30px;\" onClick=\"letswin()\">Click to start</div>");
});

function checkandbid(){
    $.get("http://www.bigibid.com/LiveResponder/LR.bid?_as="+bidnum, function(data){
        Marray = data.split("'te':'")
        time = Marray[1].split("'")
        time = time[0]
        $('#cdjs').html(time);
        if (time < 2 && able==1){
            able=0;
            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ibBid').click();
        } else {
            able=1;
        }
    });
}

function letswin(){
    setInterval(checkandbid, 300);
}
```

here you can use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKZcT/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
    $('body').append("<div id=\"cdjs\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 30px; background-color: gray; box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px; left: 30px;\" >Click to start</div>");
    $('#cdjs').click(letswin);
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/LKZcT/6/

Comment: Working nice, thank you. I will accept this answer in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `letswin` in [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('body').append("<div id=\"cdjs\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 30px; background-color: gray; box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px; left: 30px;\" >Click to start</div>").click(letswin);

});
```